# Buzzer on Arduino UNO

Tags: resistors, amperage

I'm trying to connect a buzzer to my Arduino Uno to play a tone. Instead of giving a melody I will give a `HIGH` value which translates in to 5V. Since I don't want to blow up anything I think I should use a resistor. But according to Ohm's law, I need to know how much miliamps the buzzer will draw. (R = V/I and in my case, I can't find my buzzer's I).

Any ideas on what resistor I should use?

Comment: Do you have a part number for the buzzer?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your part so we can tell whether what you have is really a buzzer or a piezoelectric transducer?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I've connected it with 1.5V batery and it makes a weird sound

Comment: Well connect to a 5V supply, and make a good contact. If you don't have a 5V supply, try using 3 x 1.5V batteries in series so you get 4.5V, anyway it can not work with less than 5V. But try. If it does not make an audible tone, try rasping the contact, if you ear noise its not a buzzer. Again be sure to respect the polarity. If you are hearing the weird sound even after some time and the contacts are good (you are not shaking the contacts), its probably a buzzer that is not oscillating as it should because of the low voltage.

Comment: But again if i put 5V is it gonna blow up? If not i can try directly from the arduino digital port

Comment: Well your question is this no? If the Arduino IO pin can supply the current the buzzer drawn. If you connect it to the Arduino IO pin and it draw more than 40mA (or a bit less) yes will probably damage the Arduino. As for connecting to a 5V power supply by a small time, the changes to damage the buzzer or transducer (if its rated for 5V), are very small. You don't have a 5V supply?

Comment: No but i can use few 1.5v AA

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis well, the "problem" is that without additional components you will not get 5V with these AA batteries, as you probably know. Anyway, it can work with 4.5V, or not be damaged by 6.0V, try the first option and say what you get. Most of the buzzer produce a fixed frequency tone in the 2Khz range at some decibels, its not difficult to distinguish if the type is that, also do not put your ear near its loud :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the part number it's difficult to tell whats the current consumption of the device at the specified voltage.

So what I suggest is. Be sure it's voltage rating is 5V. Connect a 5V supply to the buzzer by a small time, it should have polarity marking, respect it. If it produces a tone (not a click or something like 50/60Hz hum), its a buzzer (it has its own oscillator and amplifier and transducer).

Being it a buzzer, use a current-meter (a multimeter in the DC current mA scale for example), connecting one point of the multi-meter to the supply, the other to the buzzer, and the other point of the buzzer to the supply, always respecting the polarity. This will show to you what is the average current consumption of the buzzer.

The Arduino UNO probably uses a ATmega168P or ATmega328P, the maximum current per IO pin is 40mA (but the maximum total supply is 200mA, so you need to respect this value with some margin even if the IO pin max current is 40mA).

If the buzzer draw more current than the uC I/O can supply, you can try adding a resistor according to the current, but it probably wont work or work out of the specifications.
A NPN transistor will help you

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f35FiT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A general purpose NPN transistor that can handle the current and voltage can be used, also should have the necessary current gain.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the buzzer you're using. Without knowing the part number, you won't be able to use it properly.

Just as Majenko helped me notice, I've never used a buzzer myself (though I had, but didn't - the nomenclature seems to be very confusing). So, I only worked with piezoelectric transducers like the UCM1205APB ([datasheet](http://www.soldafria.com.br/datasheet/BUZZER_3_A_12V_CONTINUO.jpg) - see the column for the 5V part). I'll show you how I calculate my series resistance for it, just in case yours is similar to one of these.

According to the datasheet, it's specs are:

- Operating voltage: 5V
- Max current: 40mA
- Coil resistance: 47Ω

Using Ohm's law,

$$V = RI$$

we can see that, without a series current limiting resistance, the buzzer coil resistance will let **100mA** pass through it. That's past its maximum current rating, so we need to take it to a lower level.

We need to leave some room below the maximum rated current of **40mA** and also stay within safe current levels that the Arduino output pin can source or sink, which is about **20mA**. So let's shoot for that (**20mA**). That means we need to have **250Ω** total resistance.

$$R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{5[V]}{0.020 [A]} = 250\Omega$$

The buzzer already has 47Ω, so wee need to place we need to place a series resistor of **200Ω** to get to the **250Ω** that we want.

But **that's in my case**. You need to find your part's datasheet. If you have a piezo, you'll have to find its max rated current and coil resistance and do the math for your part. Ask your supplier for the datasheet, and if he or she doesn't have it, ask for the part number and look for the datasheet online.

If you really have a buzzer, then I won't be able to help you.

Comment: What you have there is not a buzzer, but a piezoelectric transducer - a very different thing.

Comment: Well, since i dont know anything about the buzer can i take a resistor starting from 600Ω and start going down?

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for pointing it out. It's good to know the name of things. So, Meletis, can you take a look at what you have and compare with my datasheet, to confirm whether what you have is a buzzer or a piezoeletric transducer?

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis - take note of Majenko said and make sure what you have is a buzzer. If it is, just disregard my answer.

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis FYI, a buzzer is a device you apply a DC voltage to and it makes a noise.  A transducer you have to apply a waveform to it to make a noise, like a speaker (using the Arduino's `tone()` function).

Comment: @Majenko - that's really confusing... can you help me clarify this? Looking at google, I think what I have is [a buzzer](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=buzzer&client=firefox-a&hs=bcb&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=nce5U7ylOrPMsQSr_oCgCw&ved=0CDgQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=913) and not a [piezoelectric transducer](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=piezoelectric+transducer&client=firefox-a&hs=ZLw&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=gMi5U7ieIMamsATYg4HwBA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=913).

Comment: The transducer is a thin plate like [these](http://annon-piezo-technology-co.tradenote.net/images/users/000/278/957/966671.jpg), right?

Comment: The problem is people often sat buzzer when they mean transducer. also a lot of buzzers look like transducers because the largest part of it is a transducer.

Comment: Put that plate in a little black plastic casing and you have your "buzzer". It cannot make a tone by itself, you need to oscillate it. It's a speaker. An actual buzzer includes an oscillator to generate the tone so all you need to provide is a voltage.

Comment: @Majenko Excellent, thanks for explaining it to me. You saved me the embarrassment of asking that question on the site. Or maybe I should... In any case, I'll ask the OP to specify a part number or to post a picture and if he really has a buzzer, I'll change my answer or just delete it altogether.

Comment: @Majenko - last question... so, a buzzer makes only one tone, while one can play different notes on a piezo, by oscillating it at different frequencies? That would be a good way to differentiate them.

Comment: Almost. A buzzer has a fixed tone or sound pattern. Some play multiple tones (doo-dah-doo-dah) and some do various sweeps. These are more often referred to a sirens though. But yes, you can't change how they sound, but a transducer can make any sound, even play music.

Comment: The buzzer has an oscillator, normally with a piezo transducer :) The transducer does not has oscillator (be it of fixed frequency and amplitude or not), simple as that.

Comment: @Majenko then a transducer is definitely what I have. I bet that that's what the OP has too. I've changed my answer accordingly. But if he really has a buzzer, I'll delete it.

Comment: The UCM1205APB is not even a piezo. It's a speaker with a coil.

Comment: Mine looks like Ricardo's image

Comment: In that case you have a transducer (peizo or otherwise) and you won't get any sound out of it just writing a HIGH. Measure the DC impedance (resistance) and use that in the above calculations. And use the tone function on the Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko why!? the buzzers have the same package as the image Ricardo posted.

Comment: 99.9% of the time if they look like that they are a transducer. Buzzers are usually (though not often) larger, but transducers can still look like the larger buzzers.

Comment: Well if 99.9% (this is so wrong, panel buzzers can much bigger) they look like transducers why you said it has a transducer? http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Electromagnetic-Buzzer-5V-ST-12-9_549102388.html